# Very troublesome issue with Bendy Bones (Blender 2.8)

Tags: mesh, bones

For some reason as I've worked on my model, with bendy bones, symmetrizing them causes an issue with the "Stretchy to" constraints and I don't understand why it's been doing this. I've learned I cannot connect bones to parent bones will stretch and deform the mesh horribly, the new issue I've run into is that when symmetrizing a limb or even for the eye brows, the new right bone doesn't set itself up like the left bone when I go to work on it in pose mode, it instead flips the opposite direction it should go in and when I try to reset the Stretch To Constrain for the right in hopes to fix it, it will instead affect the left bone than the selected right bone.

I don't know why it is doing this but it's causing more frustration than it is worth.

Comment: It'd be good if you could add a blend file.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think I may have found the solution, but it'll also require me to go back over a few things with the constraints such as armature constraints. I don't know about uploading the file here because it's considered nsfw and I don't know if people would be comfortable with that here.